Loss of power to bathroom and bedroom to single pole breaker
I have unplugged everything. Immediately trips breaker. Replaced old breaker, still tripping. Checked outlets and lights switches,all ok. So it's the wiring itself then?

Please take a nice clear picture of the breaker box identifying the breaker in question and [edit] it into your post. Has there been any work involving nails or screws into the walls recently?

Or electrical work anywhere in the house?

Is the breaker a plain breaker or AFCI or GFCI?


So it's the wiring itself then?

That, or a device/junction you haven't yet found or don't realize is on the same circuit. Or something you looked at and thought was good, with some sort of non-obvious internal failure - but that's somewhat unusual, whereas a hot wire shorting to the box is pretty common depending on workmanship, and may not be particularly burnt-looking.
Disconnect and cap/isolate the wires at the first device (or what you believe to be the first device) on the circuit. If the breaker does not trip, that piece of cable is good. If not, you know there's a problem in that section of cable. Work from the breaker out, or divide the circuit in the middle (if you know where the middle is) to successively identify good and bad segments until you have narrowed it down.
